# Additional help needed using browser.find_by_xpath('//h4[contains(text(), "' + "[Partial Text Within Text I Want]" + '")]')

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to grab the full text of column headers from a table. The following is not found

```
<h4><span style="font-size: 1em;">December 2014 Land Values</span></h4>
```

but I do get all subsequent elements because they are like

```
<h4>November 2014 Land Values</h4>
```

I am not sure how to deal with the extra `span` that is within the first element when searching using

```
browser.find_by_xpath('//h4[contains(text(), "' + "Land Values" + '")]')
```

As you can see, on certain pages the `span` is not present on any of the elements. As these are months, I expect 12 elements to be found but in some instances, only 11 are returned due to this extra `span`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`text()` looks at only the level specified but you can instead use `.` to look at all descendant levels.

```
browser.find_element('//h4[contains(., "' + "Land Values" + '")]')
```

BTW, that would be easier to read if you use [`f` strings](https://peps.python.org/pep-0498/),

```
search_text = "Land Values"
e = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, f'//h4[contains(.,"{search_text}")]')
```

NOTE: `find_by_xpath()` syntax has been deprecated. You should switch to `.find_element(By, locator)`. I've updated the method in my samples above.

Comment: Thanks! I've been using the [Splinter](https://splinter.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) (Python Selenium wrapper) package and was trying to minimize imports like `from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By`. I'll start moving away from deprecated code shortly. Thanks again!